# ¿Es posible llamar una Consulta como procedimiento sin utilizar PUNTO Y COMA?

Tags: mysql

Como verán en la consulta MYSQL foto hay DOS grupos de códigos.
En los FROM existe una llamada a DailyQuote (que sería el código de la derecha) que es la misma para los 4 casos.
No tengo IDEA como hacer para llamar al mismo Procedimiento 4 veces.
No se puede usar ";" por el PHP.
Si alguien sabe, yo por ahora NO.
Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

AQUI VA EL CÓDIGO IZQUIERDO (VEAN QUE LLAMA A DailyQuote):

```
SELECT
`idmA`
,`diaA`
,`precioA`
,`MM3`
,`MM5`
FROM
(
SELECT
A.idm  AS `idmA`
,A.dia AS `diaA`
,A.precio AS `precioA`
, ROUND(AVG(B.precio),2) AS `MM3`
FROM
(SELECT idm AS `idm`, MarketDate AS `dia`,ClosingPrice AS `precio`  FROM DailyQuote ORDER BY idm ASC) AS A,
(SELECT idm AS `idm`, MarketDate AS `dia`,ClosingPrice AS `precio` FROM DailyQuote  ORDER BY idm ASC) AS B
WHERE  (A.idm - B.idm)>=0 AND  (A.idm - B.idm)<=2
GROUP BY A.dia
ORDER BY A.dia ASC
) AS X1,

(
SELECT
C.idm AS `imdC`
,C.dia AS `diaC`
,C.precio AS `precioC`
, ROUND(AVG(D.precio),2) AS `MM5`
FROM
(SELECT idm AS `idm`, MarketDate AS `dia`,ClosingPrice AS `precio`  FROM DailyQuote ORDER BY idm ASC) AS C,
(SELECT idm AS `idm`, MarketDate AS `dia`,ClosingPrice AS `precio` FROM DailyQuote  ORDER BY idm ASC) AS D
WHERE  (C.idm - D.idm)>=0 AND  (C.idm - D.idm)<=4
GROUP BY C.dia
ORDER BY C.dia ASC
) AS X2

WHERE `imdC` = `idmA`
```

ESTE ES EL DAILYQUOTE. ESTRATEGIA:  DailyQuote es reemplazada por TODA LA CONSULTA ABAJO llamada "C2".

```
(
SELECT
C1.ID AS idm
,C1.intervalo AS MarketDate
,C1.instantanea AS ClosingPrice
,C0.maximo
FROM
(SELECT MAX(idfaena) AS maximo FROM registrofaena WHERE fecha='2019-10-01') AS C0,
(
SELECT
A.idfaena AS ID
, CONCAT(TIME(A.fechahora),' - ',TIME(B.fechahora)) AS intervalo
, @segundos:= IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,A.fechahora,B.fechahora),0) AS `Seg real`
/*Concepto para demoras: Si Hay demora y no supera el estándar --> 30 seg SINO Cuento demora */
, IF(B.comentario='Empieza un nuevo día', @segundos:=30, @segundos:=@segundos) AS 'Nuevo Día'
, IF(B.comentario='Desayuno', IF(@segundos>1800,@segundos:=@segundos-1800,@segundos:= 30),@segundos:=@segundos) AS 'Desayuno'
, IF(B.comentario='Almuerzo', IF(@segundos>2700,@segundos:=@segundos-2700,@segundos:= 30),@segundos:=@segundos) AS 'Almuerzo'
, IF(B.comentario='Cambio de tropa sin limpieza', IF(@segundos>900,@segundos:=@segundos-900,@segundos:= 30),@segundos:=@segundos) AS 'CTSL'
, IF(B.comentario='Cambio de tropa CON LIMPIEZA', IF(@segundos>1320,@segundos:=@segundos-1320,@segundos:= 30),@segundos:=@segundos) AS 'CTCL'
, IF(B.comentario='Parada mantenimiento Preventivo', @segundos:=30, @segundos:=@segundos) AS 'PMP'
, @segundos AS seg
, B.comentario
, @instantanea:= ROUND(3600/@segundos,1) AS instantanea
FROM
(SELECT @segundos:=0) AS z1,
(SELECT @instantanea:=0) AS z2,
(SELECT idfaena, fechahora, DATE(fechahora) AS `fechaA` FROM registrofaena) AS A,
(SELECT idfaena, fechahora, DATE(fechahora) AS `fechaB`,comentario FROM registrofaena) AS B
WHERE A.idfaena+1 = B.idfaena AND `fechaB` = '2019-10-01' AND `fechaA` = '2019-10-01' AND IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,A.fechahora,B.fechahora),0)>15
GROUP BY Intervalo
) AS C1
) AS C2
```

Comment: Por favor coloca el código como texto pues en imagen es muy difícil leerlo y no se puede reproducir tu problema, checa [ask]

Comment: No pido Control de código!, leer por favor antes de Objetar!

Comment: No es por control de codigo.. es que muchos tienen las imagenes bloqueadas o no pueden agrandarlas.. pone las dos versiones en tal caso...

Comment: No termino de entender la pregunta. Que es dailyquotes?

Comment: DailyQuites es una Consulta. La cita el FROM!!